# Stuck at adding a character to a string

Tags: c, string

I have written some code that makes a character that the user chooses to be erased from the string and now i want to add a character in the end that the user chooses. Its the first time i do something like this so i am really lost on what needs to be changed/added. I think i need to use strcpy to copy the string that the user writes and then make the new string to somehow be added to the first string, this is the part im lost on becuase i want to use the same code and just make some changes so the difference can be seen between adding a character and removing a character.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about professional or enthusiast programming. CS students should ask their TAs.

Comment: @Ben and why do you assume CS students cannot be enthusiast programmers? And why do you reject a question simply because it comes from a CS student? I am not arguing this is a good or a bad question, I am arguing your reasons for dismissing this question. Good questions can come (and have surely come) from students and bad questions (as defined by this site policy) have come from profesional or enthusiast programmers. Judge the question on it's on merit, not on where it came from.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!.. amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Are you expecting us to edit your code to make it compile?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you debug it.

Comment: the posted code is missing some lines at the end.  Please correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is apparent that you are having a bit of difficulty grasping the use of user input functions and the overall logic of your program. What do you think the following does?

```
    printf("Enter a sentence: \n");
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
    if (fgets(str, 100, stdin) == NULL) {
        ...
```

How many sentences is the user expected to enter? Calling `fgets` twice does not appear to be what you intend -- once is enough (remove the one you fail to check the return on) While duplicating the `fgets` call was not what you needed, using `fgets` for user-input was the correct choice.

(also **note:** do not return *negative* values to your shell, e.g. `return -1;`, instead simply return `1` to indicate an error condition (or the macro `EXIT_FAILURE` provided in `stdlib.h`, which is curiously defined as `1`)

While we are talking about defined constants, avoid the use of *magic-numbers* in your code (e.g. in `char str[100];`, `100` is a *magic-number*). Instead:

```
#define MAXC 100    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    char str[MAXC] = "";
```

Since you declare `str` as an array of `100` characters, you know that you do not need to prompt for entry of a character to add if you already have a string of `99 chars` plus the *nul-terminating* character. So you need to save the length of the string. Your use of `strcspn` is a good way to trim the trialing `'\n'` from `str`, but you are already scanning forward in `str` to find the `'\n'` and *nul-terminate* the string there -- and -- `strcspn` returns the number of characters of the initial segment of `str` that does not include `'\n'` (i.e. it will return the length, so simply save it)

```
    str[(len = strcspn(str, "\n"))] = 0;    /* save len */
```

The remainder of the code is simply to check the `len < MAXC - 1` to ensure that there is sufficient room to add the character, and then prompt and call `getchar`, add the new character at `str[len]` and then *nul-terminate* `str` again at `len+1`. You could do something similar to:

```
    if (len < MAXC - 1) {
        printf ("\nEnter character to add: ");
        if ((r = getchar()) != EOF) {
            str[len++] = r;
            str[len] = 0;
            printf ("This is the sentence: '%s' (len: %zu)\n", str, len);
        }
        else
            fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
    }
    else {
        fputs ("\nerror: insufficient space to add char.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** by incrementing `len` when the new character is added, you preserve the length of the new string in `len` and it is saved for later use if needed.)

Putting it altogether, you would have something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 100    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXC] = "";
    size_t len;
    int r;

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");           /* no newline needed */
    if (fgets(str, MAXC, stdin) == NULL) {
        fputs ("fgets failed\n", stderr);   /* no need for fprintf */
        return 1;   /* do not return negative values to your shell */
    }

    str[(len = strcspn(str, "\n"))] = 0;    /* save len */
    printf ("This is the sentence: '%s' (len: %zu)\n", str, len);

    if (len < MAXC - 1) {
        printf ("\nEnter character to add: ");
        if ((r = getchar()) != EOF) {
            str[len++] = r;
            str[len] = 0;
            printf ("This is the sentence: '%s' (len: %zu)\n", str, len);
        }
        else
            fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
    }
    else {
        fputs ("\nerror: insufficient space to add char.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

(just a note, if you are not providing a conversion within your output format string, e.g. `%s` or `%d`, etc.., then there is no need to call `printf` or `fprintf`. You can simply call `puts` or `fputs` to output a literal string. A good compiler will make that optimization for you.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/straddchr
Enter a sentence: 123456
This is the sentence: '123456' (len: 6)

Enter character to add: 7
This is the sentence: '1234567' (len: 7)
```

(and if you originally enter a `99` character string, you will not be prompted to enter an additional character and an error message will display of `"insufficient space to add char."`)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Appends char to the C string.

dynamic - 1 if realloc needed. 0 if str has been statically or dynamically allocated and has enough space to accommodate the new char.

```
char *appendchar(char *str, int ch, int dynamic)
{
    char *tmp;

    if(dynamic)
    {
        tmp = realloc(str, strlen(str) + 2);
        str = tmp;
    }
    if(str)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(str);
        str[len] = ch;
        str[len + 1] = 0;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Umm... Shouldn't that be `realloc(str, strlen(str) + 2);` to **add** a character (and still have storage for the *nul-terminating* character)?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin about a week ago I was asked by the interviewer: *"what actions you take to guarantee that your code is error free"*. I answered : *Hmmm... I think I can pray ...*   :)