# Replacing specific characters that user chooses in a string

Tags: c, string, replace

I have been looking around and couldnt find a good explanation how to replace a character in a string that the user chooses so i thought i should see how you guys see it and how to best approach the coding. Ive done some fast coding to relate to (its missing a lot of code since i havent been going through it and so on but i know you guys will understand anyways)

Comment: `but i know you guys will understand anyways`...no sir, we would need [mcve].

Comment: remove the line with only `fgets(str, 100, stdin);`, you're calling it inside `if` check anyways.

Comment: `len.Replace(str[j + 1], r);`??? does not appear to be very `C`-ish..

Comment: You may find the surprisingly similar question [Stuck at adding a character to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53973927/stuck-at-adding-a-character-to-a-string/53974589#53974589) helpful. Why would you call `len = strlen (str);` after already saving `len` in `(len = strcspn(str, "\n"))`?? What character are you replacing the one being remove with? Where is that input?

Comment: which character in string must replace with your input?

Comment: @EsmaeelE the user is suppost to choose the character that should be replaced

Comment: @RudolfHakkenien and that character will replace by?

Comment: @EsmaeelE by the character that the user again chooses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this work for you. I try to not use library function and implement `lenString()`.

If entered character not exists in string, its not touch.

**Code**

```
int lenStr(char a[]){
    int i=0;
    while(a[i]!='\0'){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int main()
{  
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("which char must replace?");
    char replaceChar;
    scanf(" %c", &replaceChar);

    printf("replace with? ");
    char replaceTo;
    scanf(" %c", &replaceTo);

    for (int i = 0; i < lenStr(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==replaceChar){
            str[i]=replaceTo;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;

}
```